# Mozilla readability - unable to retrieve inner html

Tags: javascript, jsdom, readability

We notice using [mozilla/readability](https://github.com/mozilla/readability) , we are unable to retrieve innerhtml for some of the websites. Is there anything, in particular, to be done to fetch these details ?

```
    const Readability = require("@mozilla/readability").Readability; // Library used for extracting the contents from HTML
    const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom"); // Used to convert HTML to DOM objects
    let dom = new JSDOM(inputResponse.content,{url: "https://www.anghami.com/legal"});
    let article = new Readability(dom.window.document,).parse();
```

Similarly the below URL response is null

https://blog.naver.com/anupdown/221361918901

Comment: I'll bet the HTML is generated dynamically with JavaScript, not in the source HTML.

Comment: Along with what @Barmar said, those HTML values may be retrieved from a service/API after the file is loaded, so you'd have to wait for those remote calls to be completed before you could get the values. On the flip side of that, you may be able to access the API directly to get the values, if they don't have authentication/authorization set up to prevent offsite/XSS/CSRF access.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am facing same issue.